# Can Delphi be used to create and handle a custom protocol handler?

Tags: delphi, protocol-handler

We have a need to interoperate between one of our web apps and a Win32 app created in Delphi.

A colleague suggested using a custom protocol handler like `ourcompany://something` to pass information to the app.

Is this possible with Delphi (5 Enterprise), or not? If it's available in later versions, we'll look to sourcing a license for that.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "someone here suggested," it would be helpful if you provided a link to that answer to provide context for this question.

Comment: Rob: I guess 'someone here' referes to someone there, at 'ourcompany'. 'We have a need' and 'Someone here, inside the group of 'We' suggested'... :-)

Comment: Oops, yes, not very clear of me. Someone at work.

Comment: As discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047(v=vs.85).aspx  The concepts on this thread no longer work as of Windows8.  So what is the new answer for Win8? Thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244619/register-custom-protocol-handler-on-win8-in-delphi-7-2006-app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSDN has [an article explaining the whole thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx). It describes the registry entries you need to set up, and it describes the command line that Internet Explorer will use to invoke your program.

There's nothing to prevent you from writing a protocol handler in any Delphi version you want.

Answer (score 9):

A custom protocol handler is a registered COM object that implements the `IInternetProtocol` interface.

Here http://www.doogal.co.uk/plugprot.php is some information on how to implement it in Delphi.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as a matter of fact that is exactly how the IDE Welcome page works. We register a custom protocol handler for bds://.