# How to show Custom Url Protocol as a Link in the Y! Messenger?

Tags: protocols, instant-messaging, yahoo-messenger

I would like to register my custom protocol with Y! Messenger.

Please see the image below.  Y! Messenger understands `mailto:`, `ymsgr:`, but not my custom protocol `myapp:`. The custom protocol is registered on both the machine sending the IM, and that receiving.

[image: Example]

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. Perhaps I'm being dimmer than usual today. Or perhaps the question could benefit from explaining things in a little more details.

Comment: @David : The picture is a good example and i think that's totally clear . Thank you

Comment: @kermia Well, it's clear to you because it's your problem. The rest of us are guessing. I'm guessing that you IM somebody else and send them a message containing `<a href="proto://data">proto://data</a>` and it doesn't show up as a link. Is that right? If so then could it be because the other machine doesn't have `proto` registered?

Comment: @David : No , I send this message for example : **proto:id=12** and "Proto" is a registered protocol in other machine . but it doesn't become a link such as "ymsgr" or "mailto" protocols . According to to the image.

Comment: @Kermia Could you please update the question with what you have just explained in this comment? As it stands I'd vote to close.

Comment: @David : Ok you can vote to close , But i explained to you . you wanna help me ?

Comment: @Kermia I'll help if you help yourself. Please improve the question to make it easier for us to understand your problem.

Comment: @Kermia The edit didn't help much. I edited it to ask the question that has come out of Andreas' answer. It's also nothing to do with Delphi in my view.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you wish the Windows Rich Edit control to autodetect these links. But then I am afraid that this cannot be done, for according to [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787991(VS.85).aspx), Rich Edits do only autodetect URL using the predefined protocols.

Comment: No , Y! Messenger does not use Rich Edits . it's using Internet Explorer as a component .

Comment: I doubt that Rich Edit is autodetecting ymsgr:// protocol. He should be asking this question to the Yahoo! developers.

Comment: @Kermia: But Internet Explorer is a HTML control, that parse HTML documents. And if you use an A element, you say everything is fine. But if you open a plain-text file in a HTML control, at least in Internet Explorer, then *no links will be autodetected*, not even the usual ones. If you use some third-party control that autodetects links, then you really have to ask the developer of this control. Most likely he has hardcoded the most common protocols, such as http, https, ftp, and mailto, and then there is nothing you can do...

Comment: @David: It doesn't. But I wasn't quite sure what the OP is after. But see my last comment; I agree with you, basically. This is probably a 3rd party thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can [register protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246192/can-delphi-be-used-to-create-and-handle-a-custom-protocol-handler) in Windows. Then you can use it like `<a href="proto://data">data</a>`. But this will not automatically parse plain text in Yahoo/Emails/IM.

Comment: Did you read my question really ? As i said it is possible in Y! Messenger and i uploaded a picture . see that agian please ;)

Comment: @Kermia: I am sorry to say it, but even if one has read your question (even multiple times), one still has to guess about what you really mean...

Comment: @Andreas: Yes you're right . Because my English is not good and i wish i could explain it in Persian :)

Comment: And did you read my reply? :) You *CAN* register protocol and you *CAN* use it in html links (and they will work in Yahoo). But Yahoo will not automatically detect plaintext links.