# Register custom protocol handler on Win8 in Delphi 7/2006 app

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-8

We need to register our app as the default protocol handler for a custom protocol `dialphone://` (and sometimes for one of the default protocols).

Our code to do this broke on Win8 (how and why of breakage [described by MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

It is unclear to us:

- How to solve this
- What to do in code

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144154%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#registration) 
in the *Default Programs UI* section seems to say we have to use `IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI`

But it is not clear:

- How to get our app on the list of apps
- Is there any way to do this silently (so the user doesn't have to click around the UI)

Can someone lay out what we should do, and if possible examples in delphi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Registering a protocol handler in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559915/registering-a-protocol-handler-in-windows-8)

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento  This is about delphi, the one you link to is not delphi, and the answer posted is where my thread begins.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to do this silently (so the user doesn't have to click around the UI)

MSDN:

> The file type and protocol association model has changed in Windows 8. **Apps are no longer
>   able to programmatically set themselves as the default handler for a file type or
>   protocol.** Instead, now the user always controls what the default handler is 
>   for a file type or protocol.

Some help links:

http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200611/0611216695.html

I think you have some error on your register entries, so its good to post it if you can.

Comment: Diego, it isn't even clear how to get our app on the list of apps for the user to select!  We understand we can't be a default handler... OK... so user must config us.... but how do we even get on the LIST of apps for a given protocol? Poking the registry does not seem to work!

Comment: @Jonesome the response about setting it as default programmatically is there. About the register, I modified my answer.